# Trying To Create A Video Landing Page Using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replicate the Landing Page used on X Theme's [Integrity 1](http://demo.theme.co/integrity-1/), but I run into difficulty figuring out a way to keep the video full screen and focused at the center without making it the entire background. I have tried:

```
<style type="text/css">

        body {margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: green;}

        #landing {margin: 0; padding: 0; top:0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute}

        video {top:0; left:0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto; background-size: cover; bottom: 0;}


</style>

<body>
        <div id="landing">
            <video id="sey" src="seydrone.mp4#t=57,286" preload="auto" autoplay="true" muted="muted" loop="loop" type="video/mp4"></video>
            <span id="welcome">DISCOVER NATURE'S SECRETS</span>
        </div>
</body>
```

When the browser is in full-screen, it works perfect, but upon shrinking the page the landing video does not respond as per the X Theme demo does. I intend to place my nav-bar as per the demo and scroll down just the same which is why the background option is not possible.

Any help/suggestions would be thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have used some JavaScript for that, but there is a way to do it without JS.

Change your `video` styles to this:

```
video {
  // Force video to cover screen
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  // Center video
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```